# Login in a different way

Tags: users

For some reason i don't have access to `user/login` block and don't have a `region content` .
is there any way to login without them like drush,url ?

Comment: simply goto www.example.com/user

Comment: If there's no content region, then /user won't show the user login form, hence the requirement to reset the site theme first to allow display of the main page content. /user would work if content region was available though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reset the theme to bring back the content region with drush

```
drush vset theme_default 'bartik'
```

Then login at `example.com/user/login`

Comment: Another great answer :) Thx a million

Answer (score 0):

You can login using the following drush command:

```
drush user-login
```